EntityFramework Core 8: IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory interface is missing after upgrade from EF Core 6
After upgrading the project from .NET 6 to .NET 8 and updating Entity Framework Core nuget-package from version 6 to version 8, I encountered the following error related to materialization of data while executing store-procedures:
Error #1. IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error #2. LegacyTypeMaterializationInfo.Index: no suitable method found to override Cnhi.Common.EntityFramework (net8.0)
In EF Core 6, as per my analysis IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory instance was being used to materialize raw SQL data into DbSet objects while executing stored procedures. However, it seems that this interface is either removed or has undergone changes in EF Core 8. I couldn’t find any direct references to it in the new version from the below links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/breaking-changes
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.irelationalvaluebufferfactory?view=efcore-6.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage?view=efcore-8.0
I attempted to substitute the logic with RelationalCommand to manually handle the SQL query results using FromSql() and ExecuteSqlRaw(), but I think they don’t fully address the need for materializing raw SQL results directly into entities as the application was doing earlier.
I don't know much about what exactly the previous functionality was doing end to end, and changing the existing code might affect at other places. So, I’m looking for a way to substitute the logic that previously used IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory in EF Core 6.
        public class StoredProcedureExecutor
{
 private readonly IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory valueBufferFactoryFactory; // This is error #1
         public StoredProcedureExecutor(DbContext dbContext, string procName)
     {
         this.dbContext = dbContext;
         materializerSource = dbContext.GetService<IEntityMaterializerSource>();
         typeMappingSource = dbContext.GetService<IRelationalTypeMappingSource>();
         valueBufferFactoryFactory = dbContext.GetService<IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory>(); // This is error #1
    
         command = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
         command.CommandText = procName;
         command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     }
        private async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ReadResultAsync<T>(DbDataReader reader, Type type)
        {
            var entityType = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(type);
            var materialize = materializerSource.GetMaterializer(entityType);
    
            IDictionary<string, int> columnIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                .ToDictionary(reader.GetName, i => i);
    
            var typeMaterializationInfos = entityType.GetProperties()
                    .Select(
                        x =>
                        {
                            var columnIndex = columnIndexes[x.GetColumnName()];
    
                            return new LegacyTypeMaterializationInfo(x.PropertyInfo.PropertyType, x, typeMappingSource.GetMapping(x), columnIndex);
                        }
                    )
                    .ToArray();
    
            ICollection<T> entities = new List<T>();
            var valueBufferFactory = valueBufferFactoryFactory.Create(typeMaterializationInfos);
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                var valueBuffer = valueBufferFactory.Create(reader);
                var entity = (T)materialize(new MaterializationContext(valueBuffer, dbContext));
                if (entityType.GetKeys().Any())
                {
                    stateManager.StartTrackingFromQuery(entityType, entity, valueBuffer);
                }
                entities.Add(entity);
            }
            return entities;
        }
        internal sealed class LegacyTypeMaterializationInfo : TypeMaterializationInfo
    {
        public LegacyTypeMaterializationInfo(Type modelClrType, IProperty property, RelationalTypeMapping mapping, int index, bool? nullable = null) : base(modelClrType, property, mapping, nullable)
        {
            Index = index;
        }
    
        public override int Index { get; } // This is error #2
    }
}


That's an internal interface that shouldn't be used by applications. As the docs say This type is typically used by database providers (and other extensions). It is generally not used in application code..  What is the code doing? What's the actual question whose answer involved that internal interface in the past? It was never needed to call stored procedures. It's not needed to create SQL queries.

BTW that internal type was removed in EF Core 7. It's not a new change that would break commonly used code. We can't guess how or why your application depends on this. Please explain why it's needed and how your application uses it. Post the code as text, not images. Images can't be copied, compiled or tested

Rather than show images can you add your code and your errors to this post

looking at yoru code, have you got Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational package installed too?

@PanagiotisKanavos This belongs to legacy application code which I am working on to upgrade to .NET8. This is what I have known from my analysis:
The IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory interface abstracts the creation of value buffers, which are essential for converting raw data into entity instances. In the StoredProcedureExecutor class, it plays a key role in reading and materializing the results of stored procedures. I don't why prior developers has used this approach but there must have been some reason to use which are not known to me.

@PanagiotisKanavos The LegacyTypeMaterializationInfo class is a workaround to reintroduce the Index property that was removed in .NET 6. It ensures that the StoredProcedureExecutor can correctly map the results of a stored procedure to entity properties by maintaining the necessary column index information.

This isn't about analysis. You're using an internal interface that's only needed by providers and was removed in EF Core 7. Why? Are you maintaining a custom db provider? Instead of asking where the interface went you should look at how other open source database providers are built. Unfortunately, as this Github issue admits there aren't good docs for provider authors. You should check how the 8.0 versions of the NpgSql or MySqlConnector providers work (MySqlConnector has nothing to do with Oracle's MySql/Connector provider)

You should ask for help at the EF Core GH repo too. roji built NpgSql and ErikEJ built EF Core Power Tools, Sqlite and SQL Server Compact Edition providers. They know far more than most people about creating providers

@PanagiotisKanavos thankyou! really appreciate your inputs. Sure, I will check on GH repo too.

@SimonPrice Yes, I tried to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational package as well but still same error persist.

You should just use SqlQuery method

@PanagiotisKanavos I have updated the code details in the description.

As ErikEJ said, why not just use SqlQuery? You never needed to write your own provider to run stored procedures. You could always run stored procedures and map the results to entities, whether the method was called SqlQuery, FromSql, FromSqlRaw etc as the docs show. EF Core 7 added the ability to map Insert, Update, Delete to stored procedures.

I think they don’t fully address the need for materializing raw SQL results directly into entities that's incorrect. In any case, you just can't change a few lines in obsolete code to make it work with new APIs. You have to find out what isn't covered by EF itself and address it. It's quite possible the problem isn't in EF at all, but a missing relation to other entities, or attempts to load related entities through stored procedures. We can't guess.

@PanagiotisKanavos I agree with you. We are re-writing the code to execute store procedure as per latest interface methods available in EF Core 8.
